# Make object sent useable in xamarin.forms cs file

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list of news, when a news is clicked it sends the user to a new page with the specific newsitem.

On the news item page I want to manipulate the object sent so I can change values within this object.

My ItemTappedEvent looks like this

```
public void goToEvent(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var selectedItem = e.Item; // model
        Navigation.PushAsync(new eventItem(selectedItem)); // pass the selected whole item from list to DetaiPage 'selectedItem' using constructor
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

    }
```

My NewsItem page handles this as a c# object like this

```
public eventItem(object selectedItem)
    {

        this.BindingContext = selectedItem;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

Within my "selectedItem" is a value named "product_wheelchair"
If this has the value "true"
Do I wan't to change it to "Ja". How can i convert my object "selectedItem" so this is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess for this it would make sense to create a ValueConverter. Have you considered that?

Comment: it's seems a lot of work for something I can do in the parent page with a loop? :) i wondered if there were a way i could make it a loopable object

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted to see this in a list with data binding, my mistake. But still, if you want to take MVVM seriously, I would say converting "true" to "ja" is purely a visual thing. So, you should just set the `BindingContext` as is and use the value converter. But, for your question, you don't hit the `eventItem` method at all? How do you call it?

Comment: object doesn't support foreach iterator so there is something wrong in your sample. Also if we assume selectedItem is soem IENumerable you still can't have seletectItem[item]. Too many syntax errors to be considered for answering.

Comment: This is how i send my object https://hastebin.com/ezasozobew.cs

Comment: It was also to explain how i want to manipulate my object, i know this is not the right syntax, but just an illustration. @IvanIčin i thought stackoverflow was here to help each other not criticise.

Comment: If that is all then the question needs to be closed as this isn't the proper illustration, you need to put the effort in making the proper question if you expect someone to put in effort to answer as clearly he has less interest in your question than you do and if you don't show interest to invest time don't expect other people will either.

Comment: @IvanIčin I have now edited my question. Is that better?

Comment: Yes, I can see that my answer I deleted is correct one, previously it was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the object to your class like:

```
var mySelectedItem = selectedItem as myClass
```

After that you can access the properties/fields available in myClass. Obviously if those are `private` you need to make them `public` to be accessible.

Comment: But it is already a class of my own called RootObejct2, if i log my object the output is:  "ODEON.Models.RootObject2"

Comment: OK I first deleted because the sample has so many syntax errors that I wasn't sure this was a problem. However according to your comment, yes this is the problem. As the class is not declared as anything other than object you can't access its properties.